What does these messages means while I compile a flutter program with NetworkImage?
I am using flutter 3.19.6 to compile a program which
 import '_network_image_io.dart'

if (dart.library.js_util) '_network_image_web.dart' as network_image;

but the the following messages appeared. Is there anybody has encounter this problem? And how to fix it?
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
/C:/dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:1406:89: Error: The constructor function type 'NetworkImage/*1*/ Function(String, {Map<String, String>? headers, double scale})' isn't a subtype of 'NetworkImage/*2*/ Function(String?, {Map<String, String>? headers, double scale})'.
 - 'NetworkImage/*1*/' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_web.dart' ('/C:/dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/_network_image_web.dart').
 - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'NetworkImage/*2*/' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart' ('/C:/dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart').
const factory NetworkImage(String? url, { double scale, Map<String, String>? headers })=network_image.NetworkImage;
                                                                                        ^
Failed to compile application.

Exited (1).

I have tried the 'flutter doctor' to fix this problem, but still not work.
Does anyone know how to fix it?

Please also show the code, use the code format in the post tools.

// the code which got problem is here
// located in image_provider.dart
//
const factory NetworkImage(String? url, { double scale, Map<String, String>? headers })=network_image.NetworkImage;

/* the bug is fixed, the error is causing by this code :  leading:Image.network('https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Screen-Shot-2020-10-30-at-8.02.23-AM.png?resize=1200,864'), /
/ the original code in image_provider.dart is as following but got some error while building /
const factory NetworkImage(String? url, { double scale, Map<String, String>? headers })=network_image.NetworkImage;
/ I update the code to, the difference is  a '?'  */
const factory NetworkImage(String url, { double scale, Map<String, String>? headers })=network_image.NetworkImage;
